# How to connect to Microsoft Graph (Connect-MgGraph) from Azure Powershell Function to a B2C directory/tenant?

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I have a need to add/remove/edit Azure B2C users from an Azure Powershell Function.
I cannot find any way to connect to the MS Graph for the B2C directory without an interactive logon.

I have successfully connected a function to my main AzureAD directory using a Managed Service Identity.  However, such cannot be used to access B2C (from what i have researched).

Given that MS Graph requires modern authentication (OAuth tokens) i don't think i can use a simple username/password combo and tests have shown such to not work from an Azure Function.

I've also tried to use a certificate, but i receive an error with `Connect-MgGraph` of 'certificate does not have a private key'.  I uploaded a *.cer file of my certificate to the app registration that i tied to the Azure Function...but a *.cer file will only contain the public key.
My research on this also shows that certificate based authentication with Connect-MgGraph only allows for pulling a certificate from the windows 'user' certificate store which doesn't exist in an Azure Function (at least from what i have seen).

Locally, i can do what i need in a normal powershell window with the B2C directory using `Connect-MgGraph -TenantID 'MyB2CTenantNameHere.onmicrosoft.com'` and after the interactive logon i can list and manage B2C user accounts.

I also tried getting an access token first using `Get-AzAccessToken`...but that also doesn't seem to work the way i need.
I tried to get a token specific to my B2C tenant using `Get-AzAccessToken -TenantID $IDofMyB2CTenant -ResourceUrl 'https://graph.microsoft.com'`, which succeeds and allows the graph connection, but it ends up connecting to the AzureAD directory and not to the B2C (even though i provide the B2C identity).
Lastly, it seems that `Connect-MgGraph` with a combination of -TenantID and -AccessToken are not allowed (errors thrown stating as much) and are mutually exclusive.

I'm choosing to use the MS Graph because Microsoft has stated that the AzureAD powershell modules are out of support and will be disabled soon.

Maybe this just isn't possible from an Azure Function??

Has anyone been able to do this?

Thanks for any suggestions or guidance!

Comment: I *may* have solved this...waiting for feedback before posting my own answer.

Found a MS article (Use a TLS/SSL certificate in your code in Azure App Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code) that may have hinted the solution.  It suggests adding an application setting of a certificate's thumbprint to link it all together.

so far i'm able to call Connect-MgGraph with -CertificateThumbnail and it connects to my B2C directory.   

Going to test some more and if after a couple of days it still works properly i'll post all the details.

Comment: Ugh... -CertificateThumbprint...  sorry for the mistype in my previous comment.